# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret.arules'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, arules, pycaret

I want to use the Association Rule Mining package from PyCaret. I installed the same using:

```
pip install pycaret[full]
```

However, when I try to import the arules module, I get the ModuleNotFoundError:

```
>>> from pycaret.arules import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycaret.arules'
```

What should I do to be able to use the association rule mining module?

Comment: Which version of `pycaret` are you using? You can check it by `import pycaret` and then `print(pycaret.__version__)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arules` module was [removed](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/3439) from Pycaret versions `3.x`. If you really need to use `Arules`, then you need to downgrade your Pycaret to at least `2.3.10`. I tested with Pycaret `2.3.5` and it works fine:

```
pip install pycaret==2.3.5
```